# Where to find User Interface (UI) design patterns for Windows applications?

Tags: windows, design-patterns, user-interface, windows-7

I don't know if this question really suits here, but we'll see :)

For web applications there are sites like [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/) and [UI-patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/), which have a great collection of design patterns used in UI's. I can't seem to find any websites/books/articles which cover design patterns **for Windows Applications**.

The only useful resource I found is [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx).
Could you suggest other resources, like books/websites/articles which covers guidelines/patterns like this?

*Not programming patterns, but design/lay-out patterns*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/) for example. A large library of UX patterns with description and examples.

Comment: I followed the link. The things I was looking for only displayed web stuff. But I've found some application patterns! Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

These are some of my links, but I'd like to know more as well:

1. [Welie](http://www.welie.com/)
2. [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main)
3. [UI-Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/collections)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now have [User experience (UX) Design Patterns for Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500.aspx). Plus they have more guidance for Metro style UX [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779072.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You shold take a look at the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern. It's for WPF and not for winforms, but if at all possible for you I would recommend using WPF instead of the old winforms.

Comment: I see that covers programming patterns, I'll save that link for later. But in this case, my question covers design related patterns :)

Comment: Oh, ok sorry. I guess I misunderstood your question then :-)